# Grid view in React Native Flatlist

Tags: react-native, gridview

How can I achieve such a view like this in react native in a FlatList component?

Usually in web It's easy with css grid but I could not a way to do this in react native.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to render an `n by n` grid, you could utilize FlatList's `numColumns` property. Then you could just pass the data into the FlatList's `data` property to specify how to render each cell in the grid by passing a function in the `renderItem` property.

A rough example would look like this:

```js
import { FlatList } from "react-native";

<FlatList 
  data={myData}
  numColumns={3}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <MyCellComponent cellData={item} />}
/>
```

However, your question is a bit different as you want to render an uneven grid. You could divide the grid into two separate components, ComponentA and ComponentB, and render them inside of a ScrollView as such.

[image]

A rough code example would look like this:

```js
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";

<ScrollView>
  <ComponentA />
  <ComponentB />
  <ComponentA />
</ScrollView>
```

Although, if you really want to use a FlatList, then you could create a 3rd component, ComponentC, which would basically wrap the previous example like so:

```js
import { View } from "react-native";

function ComponentC() {
  return (
    <View>
      <ComponentA />
      <ComponentB />
      <ComponentA />
    </View>
  );
}
```

and then render that inside of a FlatList:

```js
<FlatList 
  data={myData}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (<ComponentC data={item} />)}
/>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for you detailed answer. I really appriciate that. But i find out another practical solution for this. I used lodash to separate the items to chunks 4 by 4 and gave them a index within the FlatList,  and simply i change the styles of every 1 of 3 chunk. But you solution is useful as well.

Comment: @Ozzie can you clarify this solution a bit more? It sounds like it would be really helpful for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: No, actually there was a easier method to use this layout.  Firstly i parsed my date to chunks using lodash.  so each row has 3 items. then i used a very basic math to calculate using the index number of the row... for example if its  index === 3. then set the boxes 1 big and 2 small using flexbox...  thats alll

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to use FlashList https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/guides/masonry

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { MasonryFlashList } from "@shopify/flash-list";
import { DATA } from "./data";

const MyMasonryList = () => {
  return (
    <MasonryFlashList
      data={DATA}
      numColumns={2}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
      estimatedItemSize={200}
    />
  );
};
```